# Magento Integration upgrade to TLS 1.2

Tags: magento, soap, tls1.2

I've received the notice that one of my servers will disable early TLS and use only TLS1.2. And they said to upgrade the protocols from my soap integrations.
Is it really possible? And so, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ensure that whatever you use that calls to Magento utilizes TLS1.2 (or at least supports it as a fallback).

For example, if you wrote a program to call Magento SOAP web services in Java, you would need to make sure that it was a version of Java that supported TLS1.2, and that your configuration of Java utilized that as a protocol.

Comment: Basically it depends on exactly what technology you are using to call the services before you can know the specific steps you need to take to update the clients calling Magento

Comment: Thanks, i'm using .net 4.5 framework.
And got this line on the execution: 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;